# How to reuse a subquery

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, subquery

I have a long stored procedure. Many times in the stored proc, the subquery below  (in parenthesis) is repeated.

```
and datasetid IN 
  (select datasetid from Reportingdatasetmembers
    where  ReportingDatasetID = param_in_ReportingDataSetID)
```

Can I consolidate that code since it is repeated? I.e., in SQL Server, I would declare a table variable. Then insert the rows into the table variable. Then query against the table variable. In the least, this helps apply the DRY principle.

Is there an equivalent way to consolidate this in Oracle? Oracle table collections don't seem to be the reduce the code base.

I believe that CTEs are out of the question because they cannot be reused?

Comment: Is `param_in_ReportingDataSetID` a dynamic value, or would it be fixed?

Comment: It is dynamic (a number parameter)

Comment: CTEs would be a great way to reuse the code, but I don't think they accept parameters.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just JOIN Reportingdatasetmembers in your FROM clauses?  Is this just a simplified illustration?

Comment: Probably could have joined that to each query. But was looking for a way to reduce the redundant code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Subquery factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) (aka CTEs in other database platforms) is what you need, eg:

```
with dataset as (select datasetid
                 from   Reportingdatasetmembers
                 where  ReportingDatasetID = param_in_ReportingDataSetID)
select ...
from   some_table_1
where  ...
and    datasetid in (select datasetid from dataset)
union all
select ...
from   some_table_2
where  ...
and    datasetid in (select datasetid from dataset);
```

Comment: Is tgere a way to do this whithout paying the "with penalty"? I'd like to use the subquery multiples time without forcing oracle to execute it first independently.

Comment: There’s the “inline” hint, but bear in mind that it’s not a documented hint, and it’s very unlikely to ever be documented (a fact I had confirmed to me at the recent UKOUG tech18 conference, and which I’m quite sad about), so be careful of it in your production code. Another alternative would be to use a global temporary table (GTT) to hold the data, and you can index the GTT if that’s what is behind the need to not materialize the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

@Boneist 's way is correct but I think  you should add **materialize** hint to the select. So it comes faster.

```
with dataset as (select  /*+ materialize */
                        datasetid
                 from   Reportingdatasetmembers
                 where  ReportingDatasetID = param_in_ReportingDataSetID)
select ...
from   some_table_1
where  ...
and    datasetid in (select datasetid from dataset)
union all
select ...
from   some_table_2
where  ...
and    datasetid in (select datasetid from dataset);
```

Comment: Be careful; materliaze is an undocumented hint, so it's behaviour may change. I wouldn't recommend its use in production code. I've encountered an error caused by this hint, so I'm extra wary of it! Besides, if the subquery is used in more than one place in the query, Oracle will most likely decide to materialize it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

create a variable v_query long;
and 
then declare
v_query := '(select datasetid from Reportingdatasetmembers
    where  ReportingDatasetID = 'param_in_ReportingDataSetID')'

and than call v_query 
Not tried but seen a several time working

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle you really do the same as in SQL Server. Declare a variable of a type that is a table of defined records. Something like:

```
type my_rec_type is record (v_datasetid number(20))
type my_table_type is table of my_rec_type index by pls_integer;
my_table_var my_table_type;
```

... define your parameter for the cursor

```
v_paramReportingDataSetID number(20);
```

... in the code you'll set this to a specific ID

```
v_paramReportingDataSetID:= 12345;
```

... use the cursor with the statement

```
open my_cursor for (select datasetid from Reportingdatasetmembers
    where  ReportingDatasetID = :v_paramReportingDataSetID);
```

... populate the table variable from the cursor

```
fetch my_cursor bulk collect into my_table_var;
```

... now the table/array/data is in the my_table_var variable, usable in the rest of the code.